# User defined variables not being fed correctly into other function

Tags: r, function, variables

I have created a basic function that defines 2 variables: Size and Param.

Size is just a number but Param is a word or words separated by underscores.

Here is a basic idea of what the function and data set looks like:

```
base_function <- function(Size,Param){
    step_1 <- summarySE(alldata, measurevar = Param, groupvars=c("FinalPopSize", 
    "Time"), conf.interval=0.99)
    step_2 <<- subset(step_1,FinalPopSize==Size)
    nls(Param~SSlogis(logtime,Asym,xmid,scal), step_2)
}
```

Here is what the data I am feeding into this function looks like:

```
         FinalPopSize Mut_Rate  Time   NucDiv No_Usable_Sites
10000    1e-04 16100 0.420789             300
10000    1e-04 16100 0.407146             300
10000    1e-04 16100 0.403797             300
10000    1e-04 16100 0.401119             300
10000    1e-04 16100 0.400203             300
10000    1e-04 16100 0.397348             300
```

When I attempt to run the function using: `base_function(10000,Mut_Rate)` I get back an error with nls saying:

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~Param...
```

It seems as if the variable is not getting passed correctly into `nls()` and is instead being read as "Param".

Why is this the case for this function but not `subset` or `summarySE`?

When I look at step_2 everything looks great.

Also, when I run the nls separately & outside of the function it works fine as well: `nls(Mut_Rate~SSlogis(logtime,Asym,xmid,scal),step_2)`

What am I not seeing?

Edit: `summarySE` is from `Rmisc`

Comment: You can't just pass in symbols as column names to functions. There's no way for R to know whether the name in a formula should be a a variable or a column name. If you need to build a formula dynamically, then you'd need to use a function like `reformulate`. I'm surprised that `summarySE` worked. What package is that from? Make sure to list all non-base R packages you are using.

Comment: I am unsure on how to do that. When I attempt to follow the example in the reformulate help page I get `~SSlogis(logtime, Asym, xmid, scal)` which is not the part that I am having issues with.  This is my first time seeing the `reformulate` package as well as working with functions so forgive my lack of knowledge.